# many-to-many inside one table

Tags: database

I have a relationship where my product table contains raw materials, sub-assemblies, assemblies, etc. They are all called "products" with unique productid. I don't think it fits the BOM because a BOM consists of materials merging to create sub assemblies, merged to create assemblies, etc.

This means that one raw material batch can be used on many sub-assemblies, and one sub-assembly can have multiple raw material batch. That new sub-assembly can be used on many assemblies, and vice-versa.  This is a many-to-many relationship, but at infinite levels so joining two tables would not work (like materials, assemblies tables if I had only these two levels).

Many parents, many childs inside same table, and the hirearchical model seems to handle normal hirearchy.

Could I create a "family" table with id_Parent and id_Child both keys to the same identifier in the products table? This way I could repeat one parent for multiple childs or one child for multiple parents.

Is there an other/better method to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I think this is a BOM, though the table design doesn't dictate that. Whether a product is a "material", "assembly" or "sub-assembly" is defined simply by whether it has any children (though you could denormalise that fact to the product table itself if query performance is an issue).

I've implemented this with two tables:

```
Product (product ID etc)
Components (Parent product, child product ID, quantity)
```

This works really well. In SQL Server you can fairly easily query it with a Common Table Expression to establish the "leaves" of any given BOM.

Careful with your use of the components table, though. In this example the products and components tables together give you a pattern to build a kit/assembly. For later reporting you need to effectively take a copy (or "instance" if you prefer) of the BOM and store that elsewhere. I'd probably have Product and Component describe the BOM for an assembly, and ProductItem and ComponentItem describe an actual assembled assembly representing a real item once assembly has taken place.

You *could* say `Product`/`Component` are as to `Class` as `ProductItem`/`ComponentItem` are to `object` in that the second is an *instance* of the first.

Comment: I'll try that, I could use the Components table to track time and quantity for later reporting. I am using SQL Server 2005. thanks for the reply, even Celko's book on databases did not provide a clear answer, every single example is a normal tree diagram.

Comment: Careful with your use of the components table, though. In this example the products and components tables together give you a pattern to build a kit/assembly. For later reporting you need to effectively take a copy (or "instance" if you prefer) of the BOM and store that elsewhere. I'd probably have `Product` and `Component` describe the BOM for an assembly, and `ProductItem` and `ComponentItem` describe an actual assembled assembly representing a real item once assembly has taken place.